# R: Creating a new column with desired alphabets

Tags: r, list, dataframe, data-manipulation

I am a beginner in R, so I am sorry if my question is too basic, but I would really appreciate some help in this.

```
  mydata <-
structure(list(Col1 = c(17, 28, 80, 63, 20, 
10), Col2 = c(18, 27, 89, 62, 24, 
11), Col3 = c(25, 40, 80, 65, 23, 
11), Col4 = c(27, 29, 100, 72, 34, 
6)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("row1", "row2", "row3", "row4", "row5", 
"row6"))
```

I would like to add a new column 'X'. 
For 'X', I would like to assign A for Row 1-2, B for row 3-4, C for row 5 and D for row 6.

The code I tried is..

```
mydata$X[mydata[c(1:2),]]<-A
mydata$X[mydata[c(3:4),]]<-B
mydata$X[mydata[c(5),]]<-C
mydata$X[mydata[c(6),]]<-D
```

I tried putting "" e.g. "A" when I am assigning letters, but couldn't get it to work.

I got **error message**:

> invalid subscript type 'list'

So, I tried unlisting my data, but still did not work.

Can anybody help please?

Comment: `mydata$X <- c('A','A','B','B','C','D')`?

Comment: @r2evans I could do that, but my actual data contains over 200 rows,,,, so I could do them manually, but I was wondering if there are better ways!

Comment: What is the logic of assigning 'A' to first two rows, 'B' to next two etc?

Comment: KimSoYon, I understand what you're saying. But you suggested nothing of the "complexity" of making those assignments, so I went with the literal. You can always assign *something* to all, `mydata$X <- NA_character_` (or perhaps `""` or a sane default of your most populous letter), and then overwrite individual cells with `mydata$X[1:2] <- "A"`, etc.

Comment: @RonakShah My original data are actually sequences, not numbers. I wanted to classify them into four different groups (A, T, C, G) according to the start of my sequences. So for example, if my sequence is 'AAT' I would classify it into 'A', and 'A' goes into my new column, but I already aligned the rows of my data according to alphabetical order of my sequences, so I thought I would classify sequences by its row number.

Comment: @r2evans I tired the code, mydata$X[1:91]<-"A"
mydata$X[92:102]<-"B"
mydata$X[103:119]<-"C"
mydata$X[120:188]<-"D", It worked! Thank you:))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `case_when` from `dplyr`. We use `grepl` to detect the pattern based on start of sequence and assign values accordingly.

```
library(dplyr)

mydata %>%
  #If the value starts with "AAT" assign "A"
  mutate(X = case_when(grepl('^AAT', column) ~ 'A', 
  #If the value starts with "ABC" assign "B"
                       grepl('^ABC', column) ~ 'B', 
                       #More cases
                       #More cases
  #If none of them satisfy assign `NA`
                       TRUE ~NA_character_))
```

Instead of `grepl` you can also use `startsWith` or `str_detect`.

Answer (score 2):

r2evans has answered the original question completely 
This is a new and unclear classification question: "I wanted to classify them into four different groups (A, T, C, G) according to the start of my sequences. 
That too appears to be answered by r2evans: `mydata$X[1:2] <- "A"`
Extendable to: `mydata$X <- c(rep("A",2), rep("B",2),rep("C",1),rep("D",1))`
Ronak's recent answer of course is more eloquent!

Comment: This isn't seem like an answer itself... I would delete it. You can indicate that you like an answer by upvoting it and accepting it (click the checkmark in the margin next to the answer).

Comment: The answer component~ Extendable to: ```mydata$X <- c(rep("A",2), rep("B",2),rep("C",1),rep("D",1))```  which is a quick way to address the original posters stated need of assigning classes to already sorted rows.